# Attaching ants performance profiler to asp.net-mvc site fails

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, profiling, ants

Currently my asp.net-mvc site makes the w3wp.exe process cpu run at 100%.
I figured red-gate's ants profiler should be able to give me some clues as about where I should be looking.

When I start a profiling session I can choose between IIS hosted- and dev server hosted asp.net web application. One of these look like the most logical option to choose from to me

- ASP.NET web application (hosted in web dev server)
  I pointed it to my web app's dir (where the default.aspx) is at and set the bind port to the correct port.
  Pressed the Start Profiling button
- ASP.NET web application (hosted in IIS)
  After loading and launching the project, I filled in the complete URL to my localhost (including port) and pressed "Start profiling"

Both options fail with the following exception

```
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0002DF01-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070002.  
System.IO.FileNotFoundException
  at bP.a(Boolean )
  at bP.a(Uri )
  at bT.LaunchFrontEndProcess()
  at RedGate.Profiler.Session.ProfilerSession.i()
  at RedGate.Profiler.Session.ProfilerSession.j()
```

Any ideas?

Comment: im having exacly the same issue with my MVC site killing the w3wp.exe IIS process and the CPU hitting 100%, did you resolve this issue with Ants profiler

Comment: Haven't put any effort in it since then. You could check the url provided in the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks like it's ANTS trying to open Internet Explorer, but for some reason it can't. You haven't used windows 7's ability to uninstall internet explorer by any chance have you?

Keep an eye on http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/index.htm as we're hoping to switch to using your default browser for this rather than always using IE at some point soon.

Comment: Ah, yes I uninstalled the little devil in favor of better browsers + IETester.